# Does "further on" mean "increase"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If you lie to yourself right from the beginning you use this pattern, this façade, **further on** in your process of learning the art.

What does "further on" mean in the above sentence? I guess it means "increase" but I am not sure.

Comment: Since the essence of the sentence is about process and learning, I think it means 'progress'.

Comment: "further on" does not in any way mean increase, other than time. It basically means "later", as measured in the context of the process at hand ... e.g., "further on in the book ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@shin is correct, "further on" implies progress.

You may also hear this in the more colloquial form "further on down the road" or just "down the road", with the implicit metaphor that "life is a journey". So this means "in the future".